# Handling the requirements of Django model fields that are based on other fields

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is a very simplified version of a model I'm working on:

```
class ClothingTop(models.Model):

    SWEATER  = 0
    SHIRT    = 1

    TOP_CHOICES = (
        (SWEATER, 'Sweat shirt'),
        (SHIRT, 'Shirt'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=TOP_CHOICES)
    hoodie = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    buttons = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def type_text(self):
        if self.type == self.SWEATER:
            if self.hoodie:
                return 'Hooded sweatshirt'
            return 'Plain sweatshirt'
        elif self.type == self.SHIRT:
            return 'Shirt'
```

I want to require `buttons` if the `type` is set to `SHIRT`. My first thought was to override the `save` method but I am not sure if that is necessarily the smartest way to accomplish this.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My *simplest* suggestion, and I'd believe it's the best one in practice, is that you create a `ClothingTop` `ModelForm` and set the `buttons_clean()` method on the form that will do the custom validation. This form would also have to be set for the `ClothingTop` `ModelAdmin`.

The only other way to do it is by creating a custom model field for the `buttons` field (validators won't work here because they only get the buttons field value and are oblivious to the type, other model fields). The easiest way to do it would be:

```
ButtonsField(models.PositiveSmallIntegerField):

    def validate(self, value, model_instance):
        # here we get the buttons field value and can get the type value
        # exactly what we need!

        type = getattr(model_instance, 'type')

        if type == SHIRT and not value:
            raise ValidationError('Type set to shirt, but buttons value is empty')

        super(self, ButtonsField).validate(value, model_instance)
```

I've mentioned the approach with custom fields for the sake of completeness, I think you should skip creating a custom field type *unless* it's completely generic and readily reusable on **any** model. For those special cases, just use form validation. Your models should only ensure database integrity, which you've covered with `ClothingTop` perfectly already, business rules bubble down from form validation.

Comment: With this solution, I'd have to also provide a form for the admin app correct?

Comment: yeah, you'd need to have `form = forms.ClothingTopForm` on your `ModelAdmin`. You'd need this to ensure that staff users are constrained by the business rules.